# Issues and inconsistencies with Datetime deserialize and Datetime.parse()

Tags: apex, datetime, deserialize

I recently came accross this issue with `Datetime` deserialization.

When using `JSON.deserialize()` with a random numeric value, the `Datetime` instance is created in a strange format, however, for the same numeric value input, `Datetime.parse()` throws an exception:

**Code:**

```
Datetime dt = (Datetime) JSON.deserialize('96598', Datetime.class);
System.debug(dt);
System.debug(Datetime.parse('96598'));
```

**Output:**

```
14:49:35.28 (31544333)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|96598-01-01 00:00:00

Error on line 3, column 1: System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: 96598
AnonymousBlock: line 3, column 1
```

Also, when trying to insert an SObject with the "deserialized" `96598-01-01 00:00:00` value, I get and DmlException `FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION`.

Any ideas on how to properly validate this instead of having to manually check the input String when deserializing to a `Datetime` field?

Comment: field integrity exception is because date is out of range for valid year ranges

Comment: @cropredy Makes sense, the problem is the deserialized Datetime is also out of range, but I get a "valid" Datetime instance.

Answer (score 2):

Valid SFDC date range for fields in the database is defined in [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318735&type=1&mode=1) to be between Jan 1, 1700 and December 31, 4000

So,

```
Datetime dt = (Datetime) JSON.deserialize(myString, Datetime.class);
if (dt.year() < 1700 || dt.year() > 4000) {
  throw new MyException('Date is out of range' + dt);
}
```

If `myString` is not a valid ISO date format, then the deserialize itself will throw an exception

*N.B. SFDC not a great system for Roman Empire applications*

Comment: My issue is, since `year < 4000`, `Datetime dt = (Datetime) JSON.deserialize('96598', Datetime.class);` should throw me an exception instead of giving me a "valid" Datetime. Because `96598-01-01 00:00:00` is not a valid Datetime

Comment: your example has a year 96598 which is when we're all part of the synchronicity and are no longer corporeal

Comment: Exactly. My point is `JSON.deserialize` should not take this as a valid year, the same way Datetime.parse does not, and therefore throw an exception

Comment: I guess I'd say, why not? - valid JSON should be accepted without issue and it is up to the application to decide what to do with it; `Date dt = Date.newInstance(0001,1,1);` also works fine. It would seem like the inconsistency is with Date.parse which is being too restrictive